# How to open picker in xamarin form on button click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am using below code but it is not working for me

```
public void OpenPiker(){


    Picker picker = new Picker();
    picker.ItemsSource = Mylist;
    picker.Focus();

}
```

Comment: Have you added the picker to the layout container? First add to the container, then focus the picker.

Comment: Please update the question with what you have actually tried and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What does your UI code look like? Where is the Picker located?

Comment: What platform did you use?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

If you want to use OpenPicker method in ViewModel, then I recommend you use a [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

When clicking a button, you could just send a message:

```
public void OpenPicker()
{
   MessagingCenter.Send<MainPageViewModel,List<string>>(this, "focus",MyList);
}
```

And in .cs file, receive the message and open the picker,

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPageViewModel,List<string>>(this, "focus", (s,e) =>
   {
       Picker picker = new Picker();
       picker.ItemsSource = e;
       mystack.Children.Add(picker);
       picker.Focus();
   });
}
```

If you still have any questions, let me know and we are willing to help.

---

I make a small demo to show **Picker**.

Suppose there is a **StackLayout** name "*mystack*" in xaml and you want to put the **Picker** into the **StackLayout** and focus the **Picker**:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mystack">
   ...
</StackLayout>
```

In code-behind file, you could create a new **Picker**, add it to the **StackLayout** and focus the **Picker** like the following:

```
public void OpenPiker()
{
    Picker picker = new Picker();
    picker.ItemsSource = Mylist;
    // mytack is the name of a StackLayout in xaml
    mystack.Children.Add(picker);
    picker.Focus();
}
```

Then it will add to the container **Stacklayout**. Tested both on iOS and Android.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this code is not working for me

Comment: Could you please share more details about xaml file and code-behind file? Did you use this **OpenPicker** method in the code behind or in ViewModel?

Comment: @AhsanAli If you define the OpenPicker in viewModel, then you cannot change the control in UI directly because the view and viewmodel are separate in mvvm. You may use a [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center). Please see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Picker to a Layout or as the Content of a ContentView, otherwise, it won't be part of the view hierarchy:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Picker x:Name="myPicker" />
</StackLayout>
```

Then, in your code-behind, you can call the `Focus()` method on the Picker instance, e.g.:

```cs
public void OpenPicker()
{
    myPicker.ItemsSource = Mylist;
    myPicker.Focus();
}
```

Comment: This is also not working